# Changing autocomplete in KornShell to tab key

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

So I am trying to modify my KornShell (ksh) script to improve performance, and I am having trouble with the autocomplete option.  I am used to it being the tab key, which is easy, but for the ksh it is either esc-esc for emacs mode or esc-/ for vi mode, which is annoying to have to press every time.  Is there any way to change this to a different key without switching over to bash?  I have looked around for something involving key binding, but have gotten no decisive results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The modern version of ksh, ksh93, is implementing tab completion. You might need to turn viraw mode on for it to work.